# Can anyone explain the components of `git@github.com:name1/name2.git`?

Tags: git, github, git-clone

I'm cloning a repo using `git clone --recursive git@github.com:name1/name2.git`, where `name1` and `name2` are specific to the project. I want to understand the meaning of each part of the string `git@github.com:name1/name2.git`. Specifically:

1. What is `git@github.com`?
2. What is `name1`?
3. What is `name2.git`?

Comment: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull#_git_urls_a_id_urls_a

Answer (score 2):

This is an SSH location.  You could also write this as a URL as `ssh://git@github.com/name1/name2.git`.

The `git` portion is the username, `github.com` is the host to which you're connecting, and `name1/name2.git` is the path component denoting the repository location, which is passed to the `git-upload-pack` or `git-receive-pack` command that's on the remote server.

In GitHub's case, the `name1` portion is the owner of the repository and the `name2` portion is the name of the repository, but Git SSH locations in general need not follow this form.

The `.git` portion on the end is optional and typically denotes that the remote location is a bare Git repository; Git will attempt to add it automatically if it's needed but you don't specify it.

Comment: `-recurse` will checkout any submodules